# Why does below code not working in Chrome

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am writing code for my own portfolio. I wanted to code one simple animation which I want to apply to my Heading. Below is the code. It's not working in Chrome(v85). Someone, please help

```css
.sm-heading {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  background: rgba(lighten($primary-color, 1), 0.15);
  animation: heading;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes heading {
  0% {
    top: -1000px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="home">
  <h1 class="lg-heading">
    Man<span class="text-secondary">ash</span>
  </h1>
  <h2 class="sm-heading">
    Software Developer & Amateur Photographer
  </h2>
</main>
```

Comment: To use top, you should change value of position to relative or absolute. But I would suggest not to use top property for animation. Instead use transform: translate(-1000px) ;

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `position: absolute;`

```css
.sm-heading {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem;
    background: rgba(lighten($primary-color, 1), 0.15);
    animation: heading;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes heading {
    0% { top: -100px; }
    100% { top: 200px; }
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="lg-heading">
      Man<span class="text-secondary">ash</span>
  </h1>
  <h2 class="sm-heading">
      Software Developer & Amateur Photographer
  </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sm-heading {
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        padding: 0.2rem;
        background: rgba(lighten($primary-color, 1), 0.15);
        position: relative; /**css top,right,bottom,left value works when you mention position**/
        animation: heading;
        animation-duration: 5s;
    }

@keyframes heading {
    0% { top: -1000px; }
    100% { top: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="lg-heading">
            Man<span class="text-secondary">ash</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading">
            Software Developer & Amateur Photographer
        </h2>
```

You need to add "position: relative" where you are applying top value.